# Android lock orientation but obtain info

Tags: android, orientation

my app is locked in portrait orientation, but i want to know is there orientation change, locking it in manifest, makes onconfigurationchange not fire when orientation is changed even if i include configchanges.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

is there any way to get onconfigurationchanged fired with this config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can mix the 2.
You can still use the accelerometer to check for orientation change though